How to determine if lib is not needed in ubuntu
binstats log determines a lot of libs as unused. Example of just two libs
unused:
   /usr/lib/liblsp-r3d-glx-lib-1.0.16.so (lsp-plugins-r3d-glx)
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liba52-0.7.4.so (liba52-0.7.4)

How to determine if the lib is not really needed and can be safely removed.

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/deborphan.1.html

Thanks, that got 13 libs, guess if I want more I have to list all unused pkgs and their dependencies and choose if they should be kept or not?

why do you bother with that? it will only clear up a few bytes (yes bytes)

Well in the last 2 weeks i went down about 2 GB, Var logs is only 526 mb so I do not know where the data went, I just installed a couple of apps and purged them. one of them installed a lot of libs. Will remove those 13 libs to see if it makes any difference.

Hmm, better give up on this way, I purged the first 3 and noticed on the third one that it also removed ubuntu-desktop-minimal, reinstalled it and restarted..

packages cache is likely (all debs installed remain on disk). There is a tool baobab that should explain disk usage. Also: if you use snap ditch those apps and install the normal version. snap saves 3 old versions for each snap (on / ) so that adds up quickly too.

1 remark: the question would be better if asked about how to find what took those 2.5 and not assume you need to remove libs ;-)

Yup, but that question has been asked many times before:) ah well since I have the space guess I will live with it.

To check if a package might cause problems if removed, use the apt-cache rdepends command (to check for reverse dependencies).
An example with libzstd1: (tail -n +3 removes the headers, and sort -u shows only unique lines)
$ apt-cache rdepends --installed libzstd1 | tail -n +3 | sort -u
  btrfs-progs
  dpkg
  kmod
  libapt-pkg6.0
  libarchive13
  libboost-iostreams1.74.0
  libcurl3-gnutls
  libcurl4
  libkmod2
  libmysqlclient21
  libsystemd0
  libtiff5
  rsync
  squashfs-tools
  systemd

This means that both dpkg and systemd depends on this package, so probably not a good idea to remove.
You could do the same for your packages:
$ apt-cache rdepends --installed lsp-plugins-r3d-glx | tail -n +3 | sort -u 
$ apt-cache rdepends --installed liba52-0.7.4 | tail -n +3 | sort -u 

And you'll get a list of packages that depend on the given package. That will tell you if it's a good idea to remove it or not.
